# ASP.NET Resources type error

Tags: asp.net, resources, master-pages

I'm working on a Web Application Project and I'm getting the following error:

**The type Resources.***{text}* **exists in both** *{Web Application Name}***.dll and App_GlobalResources.***{random string}***.dll**

Any suggestions are appreciated.

The resource files in question are there and work for other pages, except for this one master page.

Comment: Does clean and build solve the problem?

Comment: That would be so wonderful if it did.  Sadly no.

Comment: I also deleted as many temp files as I can research.  So far: %tmp%, %temp%, %windir%\temp, %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files

Answer (score 0):

I found that using GetGlobalResourceObject("{GlobalResourceFilename}", "{resourceKey}").ToString() works just as good and I can move on to other issues.